# How can I make it so ALL of my HTML loads before javascript starts?

Tags: javascript, scripting

When my page loads, some of the HTML (partial text/images) is loading and then the javascript starts (prompt comes up) before the HTML finishes loading.

I would like all the html to load, and then the script to come up. The html contains instructions to the user to use while they are interacting with the JS, and they currently aren't getting the full instructions.

I thought that putting the external JS script tag at the bottom before the closing body tag would make it do this, but it doesn't...

```js
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

while (input !== "quit"){
  //handles input>>>
  if(input === "list") {
    console.log("**********")
    todos.forEach(function(todo, i){
                  console.log(i + ": " + todo);
                });
                console.log("**********")
} else if(input === "new") {
    //ask for new todo>>>
    var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo.");
    //add to the todo array.
    todos.push(newTodo);
    console.log("You have added a todo.");
  } else if(input === "delete") {
    //ask for index of todo to be deleted
    var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
    todos.splice(index, 1)
    console.log("Your todo has been deleted.");
  }
  input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("OK, you quit.");
```

```css
body{
  border: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-left: 200px;
   padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

h1{
text-align: center;
color: #3FBF7F;
font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
font-size: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;

}

ul{
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 590px;
}

li{
  padding-bottom: 20px;

}

#dogwalk{
  border-radius: 25%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#runninggirl{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todolist.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fahkwang|Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">



  </head>
  <body>
  <h1><u> Amelia's ToDo List </u> </h1>

  <img id="dogwalk" src="dogwalk.jpg">
  <img id="runninggirl" src="runninggirl.png">
<ul>
  <li <i class="far fa-bell"></i><strong> new </strong> - Add A Todo</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-bell"></i><strong> list </strong>- List all Todos</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-bell"></i><strong> delete </strong> - Remove a Specific Todo</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-bell"></i><strong> quit </strong>- Quit App</li>
</ul>


<script src="todolist.js"></script>
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to make it wait until all the images and every thing loads, that would be adding an event listener to the window for the `load` event

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onload for this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  doSomethingElse();
};
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.onload` function in your script.

basically,

```
window.onload = function () {
   // your entire code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I put this?

Comment: todolist.js.  All your code would go where the comment "// your entire code" is.